# What can the external command `time` and the reserved word `time` time?

Tags: bash, time-utility

Bash Reference Manual says

> The use of `time` as a reserved word permits the timing
>   of shell builtins, shell functions, and pipelines. An external `time` command cannot time
>   these easily.

1. What can an external command `time` time?

   Only a simple external command? Nothing else?

   Which rule prevents it from timing other things? Does the rule
   belong to the shell (bash) or the implementation of the external
   command `time`?

   Btw, I am running Ubuntu, so `time` is from Debian.
2. Can the Bash's reserved word `time` time all the things that can
   run? If not, what can't it time?
3. What are the things that the external `time` can time but the reserved word `time` can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is about Linux.

> 1. Which rule prevents it from timing other things?

I guess it gets *time info* only for processes since it actually uses `wait4` system call for getting this *time info*. The first parameter of `wait4` is the pid of a process. So `/usr/bin/time` always call `execve` and then wait4.

By the way:

> execve() executes the program pointed to by filename.  filename must be either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of the form: #! interpreter [optional-arg]

So /usr/bin/time needs something that can be executed by `execve`

> 2. Can the Bash's reserved word time time all the things that can run?

I guess, yes. It is implemented as two group of calls:

```
10:06:03 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 152976}, ru_stime={0, 465929}, ru_maxrss=4052, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=6214, ru_majflt=1, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=368, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=6349, ru_nivcsw=12}) = 0
10:06:03 getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, {ru_utime={2, 259656}, ru_stime={1, 888712}, ru_maxrss=21176, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=64297, ru_majflt=4, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=272, ru_oublock=368, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=56077, ru_nivcsw=386}) = 0
```

*run a command or builtin*

```
10:06:04 getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 152976}, ru_stime={0, 476927}, ru_maxrss=4052, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=6243, ru_majflt=1, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=368, ru_oublock=0, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=6399, ru_nivcsw=13}) = 0
10:06:04 getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN, {ru_utime={2, 271654}, ru_stime={1, 903710}, ru_maxrss=21176, ru_ixrss=0, ru_idrss=0, ru_isrss=0, ru_minflt=64514, ru_majflt=4, ru_nswap=0, ru_inblock=272, ru_oublock=368, ru_msgsnd=0, ru_msgrcv=0, ru_nsignals=0, ru_nvcsw=56079, ru_nivcsw=406}) = 0
```

So I guess `bash` just calculate a difference and prints it. In that way it can measure anythins like own builtins or child process

> 3. What are the things that the external time can time but the reserved word time can't?

Actually both system calls `getrusage` and `wait4` get from a kernel **struct rusage usage**. However `bash time` prints limited number of fields from this structure. This is from `man 1 time`:

> Note:  some  shells  (e.g.,  bash(1))  have a built-in time command that provides less functionality than the command described here.

```
$/usr/bin/time -v  seq 10000
    Command being timed: "seq 10000"
    User time (seconds): 0.01
    System time (seconds): 0.01
    Percent of CPU this job got: 24%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.12
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2640
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 199
    Voluntary context switches: 8
    Involuntary context switches: 24
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 8
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```