# calculating the running time of a process more efficiently

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell

i need to get the running time of a program as soon as it is closed and i came up with this

```
start=`date +"%M"`
while [ `pgrep vlc` ];do
        echo vlcopen > /dev/null
done
stop=`date +"%M"`

[ $stop -lt $start ]&&time=$[ 60-$start+$stop ]||time=$[ $stop-$start ]
echo $time > time.txt
```

and it does the job but this is highly inefficient and takes a lot of cup usage how do i do this more efficiently

Comment: Read `man time`. We have a tool for that.

Comment: exactly what i need thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `time`

Note: Bash has a keyword `time` so if you do:

```
time some command
```

[that one is used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459946/140633) ,  [SHELL_GRAMMAR: bash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_GRAMMAR)

The `time` you find in man `time` is usually something like `/usr/bin/time`

```bsh
$ type -t time
keyword
```

Main point in using the *non bash* time is features like `-v` (GNU `time`).

Also see: [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556411/3342816)

Comment: BTW, you can change the output format of bash's built-in `time` with the TIMEFORMAT variable.  e.g. `TIMEFORMAT=$'\nreal %3lR\tuser %3lU\tsys %3lS'` is, IMO, a nice simple one-line format (I set this in my ~/.bashrc).    The GNU version of `/usr/bin/time` (i.e. not the bash built-in) uses the TIME variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [bash `SECONDS` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-SECONDS):

```bsh
SECONDS=0

# do stuff here, such as
sleep 5

duration=$SECONDS

echo "The stuff took $duration seconds to complete"
```

Efficiency is gained by removing the need to spawn external processes.