# Add autocomplete for time built-in command

Tags: bash

Tab completion does not work with `time` prefix:

```
time <tab>
```

How can I add the auto completion? Just want the default command completion behavior.

Comment: First of all, `time` in bash is not a builtin, it's a [reserved word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270614/why-does-bash-implement-time-as-a-reserved-word-instead-of-a-builtin). Secondly, this reserved word in bash only has one possible flag - `-p`. Why do you need autocomplete for that?

Comment: on ZSH with OMZ this works

Comment: it should also complete all possible commands. eg `time dock[tab]` completes `time docker` because docker is an available command in my system. I wish I knew how it worked as I want the same behaviour for one fo my scripts.

Comment: @Brad see [Creating a bash completion script](https://iridakos.com/programming/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial)